# Data overridding the previous one

Tags: android, json

This is my api

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Little Angels Higher Secondary School",
      "address":"Hattiban",
      "district":"Lalitpur",
      "country":"Nepal",
      "phone":"01-41111111",
      "email":"lac@gmail.com",
      "website":"wwww.la.com.np",
      "institution_type":"Government",
      "establishment_date":"15-12-2016",
      "admission_open_from":"15-12-2016",
      "admission_open_to":"19-12-2016",
      "logo":"http:\/\/www.myeducationhunt.com\/logos\/logo1.png",
      "active":0,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "latitude":27.6514,
      "longitude":85.3359,
      "fees":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "grade":"1",
            "price":12000,
            "school_id":1,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "grade":"2",
            "price":13000,
            "school_id":1,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":6,
      "name":"Baltimore Secondary School",
      "address":"Baltimore",
      "district":"idk",
      "country":"U.S",
      "phone":"1111111111111",
      "email":"bat@gmail.com",
      "website":"www.baltimore.edu.np",
      "institution_type":"Private",
      "establishment_date":"15-12-2016",
      "admission_open_from":"15-12-2016",
      "admission_open_to":"20-12-2016",
      "logo":"http:\/\/www.myeducationhunt.com\/logos\/logo2.png",
      "active":0,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "latitude":27.6514,
      "longitude":85.3359,
      "fees":[  
         {  
            "id":9,
            "grade":"1",
            "price":12000,
            "school_id":6,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {  
            "id":10,
            "grade":"2",
            "price":12500,
            "school_id":6,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {  
            "id":11,
            "grade":"3",
            "price":15000,
            "school_id":6,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {  
            "id":12,
            "grade":"4",
            "price":19000,
            "school_id":6,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   }]
```

I parsed this data in my school class as:

```
JsonArrayRequest schoolRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                OurSchool ourSchool = new OurSchool();

                                ourSchool.schoolId = obj.getInt("id");
                                ourSchool.schoolName = obj.getString("name");
                                ourSchool.schoolLocation = obj.getString("address");
                                ourSchool.schoolLogo = obj.getString("logo");
                                ourSchool.district=obj.getString("district");
                                ourSchool.country=obj.getString("country");
                                ourSchool.phone=obj.getString("phone");
                                ourSchool.email=obj.getString("email");
                                ourSchool.website=obj.getString("website");
                                ourSchool.type=obj.getString("institution_type");
                                ourSchool.estb_date=obj.getString("establishment_date");
                                ourSchool.admission_start_date=obj.getString("admission_open_from");
                                ourSchool.admission_end_date=obj.getString("admission_open_to");
                                ourSchool.latitude=obj.getDouble("latitude");
                                ourSchool.longitude=obj.getDouble("longitude");
                                // adding schools to ourSchool list

                                JSONArray fees=obj.getJSONArray("fees");
                                List<FeeClass> listFeeClass= new ArrayList<FeeClass>();//by Ahamed
                                for (int j=0;j<fees.length(); j++){
                                    FeeClass feeClass= new FeeClass();//by Ahamed
                                    JSONObject obj1=fees.getJSONObject(j);
                                       feeClass.setGrade(obj1.getString("grade"));//By Ahamed
                                    feeClass.setFee(obj1.getString("price"));//ByAhamed

                                   listFeeClass.add(feeClass);//by Ahamed

                                    ourSchool.grade=obj1.getString("grade");//you need to remove this line
                                    ourSchool.fee=obj1.getString("price");//you need to remove this line
                                }
                                ourSchool.setFeesList(listFeeClass);//by Ahamed
                                ourSchoolsListItems.add(ourSchool);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
```

I sent these data to my schooldetail class as

```
Intent i = new Intent(School.this, SchoolDetails.class);

                i.putExtra("school", ourSchoolsListItems.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
```

And finally I tried to retrieve all these data of corresponding school as

```
 ourSchool = (OurSchool) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("school");
```

All works perfectly fine. The only problem is inside "fees" object in the api. I want to display all the fees details of corresponding class. But I am just getting the fee detail of last object inside "fees". For example inside little angel's school fees array, I am just getting id,grade and price of grade2. I want to retrieve all the objects detail inside fees array. Please Help.

**UPDATE**
//By Ahamed

```
 class FeeClass{
       String grade,fee;
    public void setGrade(String grade){
      this.grade=grade;
    }
    public String getGrade(){
      return this.grade;
    }
 }
```

Add below variable in your OurSchool Class.

```
    List<FeeClass> feeClassObject= new ArrayList<FeeClass>();
```

with getter and setter as well

```
    public void setFeesList(List<FeeClass> feeClassObject){
      this.feeClassObject=feeClassObject;
    }
    public List<FeeClass> getFeesList(){
      return  feeClassObject;
    }
```

And See your for Loop code

Comment: your `fee` is an array so you have to maintain an anrraylist of  type `fee` inside every `OurSchool` object and add `fee` object into it

Comment: I got no clear idea on what u are saying.Could you please elaborate.Can u please edit my question if possible

Comment: your code updated. but it is for peer reviewed . you can see the updated code if that updated code accepted

Comment: Thank u all I got my problem fixed.Round of applause to all those who helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, your first for loop school creating one single OurSchool object. in that single ourschool object , you are trying to put all fee details in single pointer object. so, first fee details saved on that fee details object and again second fee details replacing your existing fee details object. the same thing doing until your second for loop finish. so, the last item only will be exist on that object. that's all. Happy Coding.

**EDIT**

So, you have to maintain one List on ourSchool Object.

Like,

```
class FeeObject{
 String feeDetails1,feeDetails2..etc
}
```

Add below variable in OurSchoolObject.

```
  List<FeeObject> feeObjectList= new ArrayList<>();
```

That's all

Comment: could you please elaborate this with its implementation in my code sir

Comment: Yes i do. wait.

Comment: Thank u ahamed,Now Could you please let me know how can I get this feelist inside Feetabs under SchoolDetails class under fee tab

Comment: when you selecting a sindle school, which has the feeList. based on the feeList, you need to create the tab,using for loop. that 's all Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use this modelclass to parse the json.

```
public class OurSchool {
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getDistrict() {
    return district;
}

public void setDistrict(String district) {
    this.district = district;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public String getInstitutionType() {
    return institutionType;
}

public void setInstitutionType(String institutionType) {
    this.institutionType = institutionType;
}

public String getEstablishmentDate() {
    return establishmentDate;
}

public void setEstablishmentDate(String establishmentDate) {
    this.establishmentDate = establishmentDate;
}

public String getAdmissionOpenFrom() {
    return admissionOpenFrom;
}

public void setAdmissionOpenFrom(String admissionOpenFrom) {
    this.admissionOpenFrom = admissionOpenFrom;
}

public String getAdmissionOpenTo() {
    return admissionOpenTo;
}

public void setAdmissionOpenTo(String admissionOpenTo) {
    this.admissionOpenTo = admissionOpenTo;
}

public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

public int getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(int active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public List<Fees> getFees() {
    return fees;
}

public void setFees(List<Fees> fees) {
    this.fees = fees;
}

@SerializedName("id")
public int id;
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
@SerializedName("address")
public String address;
@SerializedName("district")
public String district;
@SerializedName("country")
public String country;
@SerializedName("phone")
public String phone;
@SerializedName("email")
public String email;
@SerializedName("website")
public String website;
@SerializedName("institution_type")
public String institutionType;
@SerializedName("establishment_date")
public String establishmentDate;
@SerializedName("admission_open_from")
public String admissionOpenFrom;
@SerializedName("admission_open_to")
public String admissionOpenTo;
@SerializedName("logo")
public String logo;
@SerializedName("active")
public int active;
@SerializedName("created_at")
public String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
public String updatedAt;
@SerializedName("latitude")
public double latitude;
@SerializedName("longitude")
public double longitude;
@SerializedName("fees")
public List<Fees> fees;

public static class Fees {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;
    @SerializedName("grade")
    public String grade;
    @SerializedName("price")
    public int price;
    @SerializedName("school_id")
    public int schoolId;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    public String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    public String updatedAt;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }

    public void setSchoolId(int schoolId) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
  }
```

Then add the dependency,

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Comment: What changes i should have to do inside school and schoolsdetails class.Please help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

Do like this below. Let me know if any confusion.

```
public class OurSchool {
private ArrayList<Fees> feeList;

public void setFees(ArrayList<Fees> list){
this.feeList=list
}

publice ArrayList<Fees> getFeeList(){
return feeList;
}

}


public class Fees{
private long id;
private long school_id;
private int grade;
private int fee;
}
```

Then OnResonse Method do like this

```
JsonArrayRequest schoolRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                -------other code -------


                JSONArray fees=obj.getJSONArray("fees");


                          ArrayList<Fees> feeList=new ArrayList<Fees>;
                            for (int j=0;j<fees.length(); j++){
                                final Fees fees=new Fees();
                                JSONObject obj1=fees.getJSONObject(j);
                                fees.grade=obj1.getString("grade");
                                fees.fee=obj1.getString("price");
                                feeList.add(fees)
                            }
                            ourSchool.setFees(feeList); /// Add the feeList ///

                            ourSchoolsListItems.add(ourSchool);// Add the OurSchool ///



                }
```

Comment: your code is generating a lot of errors please have a look

Comment: hi Edward: I have just suggested the changes so that  you can get proper output. Can you please let me know what type of errors you are getting.

Comment: Actually I missed to set the arraylist to my listview.I corrected that.Now everything is working perfectly